# Facebook authentication for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I researched on various articles available on the internet..

but still i'm not able to find a proper solution for integrating facebook connect authentication with my asp.net site..

thanks..

Answer (score 2):

[Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/)